# How to get the current time in minutes from Timer component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, timer

I'm using **react-timer-hook** library for showing the timer in my **Next.js** application. The timer is working fine, but the issue is I'm not able to get the current elapsed time in minutes on the handle form event. I want to send the **total_time_taken** in minutes.

This is the Timer component:

```
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { useTimer } from 'react-timer-hook';

export default function Timer({ expiryTimestamp, functionCall }) {
    const {
        seconds,
        minutes,
        hours,
    } = useTimer({
        expiryTimestamp,
        onExpire: () => functionCall()
    });
    return (
        <Typography variant='h5' fontWeight={'bold'} component={'div'}>
            <span>{hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours}</span>:<span>{minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes}</span>:<span>{seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds}</span>
        </Typography>
    );
}
```

This is where I'm using the Timer component:

```
const time = new Date();
time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds() + 3600);
<Timer functionCall={handleForm} expiryTimestamp={time} />
```

This is the handleForm event in which I want the elapsed time in minutes in the total_time_taken object:

```
async function handleForm() {
        const token = Cookies.get('token');
        const formData =
        {
            user_id: userId,
            test_id: test_id,
            total_time_taken: 35,
            answers: answers
        }
        const data = JSON.stringify(formData);
        const resp = await axios.post(`answers`, data, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }

        });
        if (resp.data.success) {
            router.push('/user/feedback/' + test_id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you want `total_time_taken: 35` expressed in minutes somewhere? What does the value `35` represent? The minutes? Is this basically just a math problem? It's unclear what and where any issue is, specifically. Can you clarify where you are stuck?

Comment: @DrewReese 35 is just a hard coded value, there I want dynamic value of total timer elapsed time in minutes.

Comment: I'm displaying a Timer of 1 hour and when the page renders the Timer started to elapse. Now I've a form to submit if I submit the form, then I want the total elapsed time in minutes.

Comment: Ok, so this dynamic value... where is it and what time unit(s) does it represent?

Comment: @DrewReese, you can see in the above question, I'm passing a current time+3600 (seconds) in the Timer component, this time create a timer of 1 hour in the format of (hh:mm:ss), now suppose when timer shows 00:45:50, then from 1 (60 minutes) hour it elapsed 15:10 minutes, and this 15:10 minutes I want in total_time_taken

Comment: Sorry, what am I not understanding here? Can't you just subtract the time remaining from the 1 hour starting time and get the values for minutes and seconds elapsed? It's just math.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247542/discussion-between-dcodemania-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to access the state of the child component `Timer` from the parent component. This appears to be a clear case where the parent component should hold the timer state and pass the time down to the `Timer` component for display, and the parent component can easily reference the state it owns.

Example:

Timer

```
function Timer({ seconds, minutes, hours }) {
  return (
    <Typography variant="h5" fontWeight={"bold"} component={"div"}>
      <span>{String(hours).padStart(2, "0")}</span>:
      <span>{String(minutes).padStart(2, "0")}</span>:
      <span>{String(seconds).padStart(2, "0")}</span>
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

Parent component

```
const expiryTimestamp = new Date();
expiryTimestamp.setSeconds(expiryTimestamp.getSeconds() + 3600);

function App() {
  const handleForm = () => {
    const elapsed = 3600 - (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds);
    const total_time_taken = {
      hours: Math.floor(elapsed / 3600),
      minutes: Math.floor((elapsed % 3600) / 60),
      seconds: ((elapsed % 3600) % 60) % 60
    };

    console.log("handleForm", {
      ...total_time_taken
    });

    ...
  };

  const { seconds, minutes, hours } = useTimer({
    expiryTimestamp,
    onExpire: handleForm
  });

  ...

  return (
    <div className="App">
      ...
      <Timer {...{ seconds, minutes, hours }} />

      <button type="button" onClick={handleForm}>
        Yes
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-get-the-current-time-in-minutes-from-timer-component]

[image]